# Do skill points from a class mod apply if you haven't activated that skill yet?

Tags: borderlands

I am currently playing as a hunter with a primary focus on *gunslinger* and I do not have any points in *rogue* yet.  However, I picked up a scavenger class mod that adds:

+3 Team scavenge extra items
+2 Swipe skill
+2 Ransack skill 
+3 Out for blood skill

I have yet to spend any points on these skills and I do not want to waste my class mod opportunity.  Do these points from this class mod apply when I have to unlock those skills ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Class Mods take effect as long as you have at least 1 point on that skill.**

The points added from the Class Mod can stack to over 5 points adding extra effect. However, certain skills are not really worth putting more than 5 points into, such as Aerial Impact for the Hunter. I mean, whats the point of having an over 100% chance to stun enemies? That's just wasting skill points that could go to something else.

Taken from [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/942812-borderlands/answers?qid=122977).

Comment: So I'm my example, I am just wasting my class mod as I don't have any points spent in rogue?  Any chance you can source this? :)

Comment: @Foxtrot That's correct. In your example the mod you are using you wont get the full benefit from. In terms of sourcing, it came from gaming forum and personal experience, added link.

Answer (score 1):

*What am I seeing here?* I have no points in the Phoenix skill, which lights me up with fire after a kill. The COM that I have equipped adds +4 points to Phoenix. I kill something and look down to note that I am not affected by Phoenix. I put a point into Phoenix and look down to note that I am now using Phoenix.
If the COM's skill-boost could apply without any skill-points in the skill, I would have been on fire before putting that 1/5 point in.